# AngularJS передача параметров

Tags: angularjs

Доброго всем времени суток. 
Подскажите. Могу ли в AngularJS принять массив данных, отправленный через Twig на страницу обработчик? В каких-то случаях конструкцию {{data}} удаётся использовать в AngularJS, но увы, не всегда. Так-же интересует насколько печально использовать оба компонента в связке.
Ответ контроллера:

```
$info = $this->db->table('table')->where('md2', $md2)->get()->toArray();
return $this->view->render($response, 'api.twig', array('data' => $info));
```

Или подскажите, как примерно должен ответить контроллер, что-бы дальше можно было полностью работать через AngularJS.
Всем добра)

Comment: в ангуляре можно натсроить другие символы вместо {{}} для шаблонов, тогда они не будут пересекаться с twig

Comment: Это позволит работать с массивом data в api.twig средствами angularjs без редактирования контроллера, или же всё-таки некоторые поправки будут нужны? в данном случае говорю о контроллере выше...

Comment: на сколько я понял - twig это серверный шаблонизатор, ангуляр при этом - клиентский, у тебя они пересекаются только в том случае, когда обрабатывают одни и те же файлы, и так как у них в данный момент одинаково выделяются места вставок в шаблон twig может обрабатывать места которые предназначены для ангуляра. если же сменить `{{}}` в ангуляре или twig то пересекаться они больше не будут

Comment: Ок. Спасибо за инфу